# Square INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR

Tags: curl, flutter, dart, square

I am playing with Flutter and Square Sandbox and trying to charge a credit card from an app.

This is what I get as an generated cURL output:

```
curl --request POST https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/MY_LOCATION_ID/transactions \--header "Content-Type: application/json" \--header "Authorization: Bearer API_TOKEN" \--header "Accept: application/json" \--data '{"idempotency_key": "","amount_money": {"amount": 100,"currency": "USD"},"card_nonce": "cnon:CNONID"}'
```

However I get this error:

```
{"errors":[{"category":"AUTHENTICATION_ERROR","code":"UNAUTHORIZED","detail":"This request could not be authorized."}]}
```

I insert location ID and API key but still this is what I get as response. Any idea why? Do I need some SSL certificates installed or what?

**EDIT**

After some time I tried this:

```
String chargeServerHost = "http://192.168.178.35:8000";
String chargeUrl = "$chargeServerHost/buyCoins";

class ChargeException implements Exception {
  String errorMessage;
  ChargeException(this.errorMessage);
}

Future<void> chargeCard(CardDetails result) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String token = prefs.getString('token');

  var body = jsonEncode({"nonce": result.nonce, "token" : token});

  http.Response response;
  try {
    response = await http.post(chargeUrl, body: body, headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    });
  } on SocketException catch (ex) {
    throw ChargeException(ex.message);
  }

  var responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
  print(responseBody.toString());

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return;
  } else {
    throw ChargeException(responseBody["errorMessage"]);
  }
}
```

I get nonce value, but in response I get this:

```
{errors: [{code: NOT_FOUND, detail: Card nonce not found, category: INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR}]}
```

even though I have value for nonce... It is some random string generated after card entry.

Comment: Are you using your Sandbox Application ID or your Production Application ID? Is it the same environment that that corresponds with your access token? When there is a mismatch between the two, you end up with this kind of error.

Comment: Also, make sure you're using v1.2.3 if you're testing via Sandbox. https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-flutter-plugin/blob/b0d6e93f5980e300a4984d798b622ccc7241cca4/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: The string that is generated, does it look like `"cnon:CBASEEruNYMle5IA7LuxR8Ku1yZ"`?

Comment: Yes. I also tried with `cnon:card-nonce-ok` and works when I send request via Postman, but not from the app.

Comment: Oh God. The error was produced because I am returning 201 from backend and here I check if status code is 200... Programming is beautiful :D.

Comment: Programming really is beautiful :D